# Pyspark- Convert an RDD into a key value pair RDD, with the keys in ascending order

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD1 in this form: `['once','upon','a','time',...,'the','end']`. I want to convert in into a key/value pair such that the strings are values and keys are in ascending order. The expected RDD2 should be as follows: `[(1,'once'),(2,'upon'),(3,'a'),(4,'time'),...,(RDD1.count()-1,'the'),(RDD1.count(),'end']`
Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: try zip rdd1 with another rdd from range(1, n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pyspark's own zip function. This might help:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(['once','upon','a','time','the','end'])
nums = sc.parallelize(range(rdd1.count())).map(lambda x: x+1)

zippedRdds = nums.zip(rdd1)
rdd2 = zippedRdds.sortByKey()

rdd2.collect()
```

will give:

> [(1, 'once'), (2, 'upon'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'time'), (5, 'the'), (6,
>   'end')]

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.